# Ajax GET call in a razor page not breaking inside the method in the controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following javascript using ajax:

```
function MoveToWeek(weekIndex) {
    if (weekIndex == 1) {
        var index = @Model.WeekIndex;
        index = index+1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("RenderCalendar", "Calendar")',
            data: { weekIndex: index },
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#RenderCalendarArea").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if (weekIndex == -1) {
        var index = @Model.WeekIndex;
        index = index+-1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("RenderCalendar", "Calendar")',
            data: { weekIndex: index},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#RenderCalendarArea').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the following method in my controller "CalendarController":

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RenderCalendar(int weekIndex = 0)
    {
         //..snip
    }
```

I have confirmed the ajax code runs (if I put a javascript breakpoint on the $.ajax line, it'll break there). In addition the values in the ajax method do seem to be set correctly. In the debugger the javascript method has been compiled as such:

```
function MoveToWeek(weekIndex) {
    if (weekIndex == 1) {
        var index = 0;
        index = index+1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Calendar/RenderCalendar',
            data: { weekIndex: index },
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#RenderCalendarArea").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    else if (weekIndex == -1) {
        var index = 0;
        index = index+-1;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Calendar/RenderCalendar',
            data: { weekIndex: index},
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#RenderCalendarArea').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, when this code runs, it does not break inside the method in the controller. Can anyone see why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular partial view didn't use the layout file... which meant it didn't import the jquery lib. That's why it didn't work. Ooops.